# cross-gdb: fix a mismatch between libthread_db and libpthread

Tags: linux, debugging, gdb, remote-debugging

I' ve a cross-gdb configured with `--host=i686-pc-linux-gnu --target=powerpc-e300c3-linux-gnu`. i can correctly debug an application on a remote board with `gdbserver` but i get an error about a version mismatch between `libthread_db` and `libpthread` so i can't debug threads correctly (`gdb` recognizes only one thread instead of three threads). Maybe it's is due to a different version of `libc`: on host machine i've `libc2.15` and on target machine `lib2.5`. I tried to rebuid `libc2.5` for host in order to link gdb against to it but it's an hell. Before i get crazy to rebuild it, could someone confirm that it's a `libc` problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I tried to rebuid libc2.5 for host in order to link gdb against to it

That's not what you need.

What you need, is for gdb to find and load `libthread_db.so.1`, that matches your target `libpthread.so.0`.

For this, you need to

1. build `libc-2.5` for host, and
2. set GDB's `libthread-db-search-path` such that it finds the `libthread_db.so.1` built in step 1.

You don't actually need to build the entire libc in step 1. Something like this should suffice:

```
mkdir build && cd build
../configure --prefix=/usr
make -C ../nptl_db objdir=`pwd`
```

Update:

> i have GDB 6.6 and there isn't libthread-db-search-path. What is another way to specify that path?

That GDB will just `dlopen("libthread_db.so.1", ...)`. So to make it find the right `libthread_db.so.1`, you need to adjust `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. Using bash:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/tmp/glibc-2.5/build/nptl_db gdb /path/to/target/a.out
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll try to do that. However i have GDB 6.6 and there isn't libthread-db-search-path. What is another way to specify that path?

Comment: `libc` by default doesn't allow to launch `configure` inside src root dir so i have a dir `build` and launch inside it `../configure --prefix=/usr` but `make -C ../nptl_db` doesn't work due to path of config.make...any idea?

Comment: @MirkoBanchi I've updated the answer for both of your comments.

Comment: Thanks. However for now i can't rebuild ntpl_db

Comment: I have all needed libs...however gdb doesn't use them also with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable set. Maybe gdb calls `dlopen("/lib/libthread_db.so.1",...` specifying absolute path for the so?

Comment: @MirkoBanchi None of the versions of GDB  I've seen do that. You can see what GDB is doing by also setting `LD_DEBUG=libs` before invoking it.